# import clr ImportError: No module named clr

Tags: python, .net, mono, clr, python.net

I have an Ubuntu 12.04. I tried import clr in my python code and I have this error.

I went through the links. But all in vain. Is there a way to check 'clr' present?
How do I see that the module is present?

Comment: did you install pythonnet and if yes, how and which version? what is your python version?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Mono framework to run .NET on Ubuntu. Please refer the below link which helps you to install .NET framework. Then the CLR will be available for your code OR you can reference the CLR in your code after installation of Mono.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/497358/how-to-install-mono-on-ubuntu-64-bit-v14-04

Comment: Mono by itself is not enough to import it from Python, use pythonnet to connect between both